# Програма установки Windows XP не видит C:\

Tags: windows, установка, windows-xp

При установке Windows XP, программа установки считает флешку с которой я скачиваю как раздел C, но при этом не видит разделы SSD/жёсткого диска.

---

Могу уточнить любые вопросы, которые помогут решить эту проблему. Но умоляю вас, найдите решение как можно побыстрей.

[image: флешку считает как C, но нет разделов диска]

Comment: Так SSD или жёсткого диска? Это принципиально. Вы уверены, что Windows XP вообще имеет драйвера на ваше железо, чтобы быть способной обнаружить подключенные устройства?

Comment: убедитесь что те разделы имеют MBR разметку(GPT и не должен видеть). решается с помощью какого нибудь Partion Assistant(бывают в том числе и live образы для baremetal настройки)

Comment: @puffleeck, ты бы хоть про проц\мать спросил. 2023й год на дворе, 1155-й сокет ~10 лет назад релизнули - вариативность железа просто зашкаливает.

Comment: @andreymal, если контроллер sata - какая разница что на конце? Хоть яичная скорлупа.

Comment: @donRumata совсем не факт что контроллер sata

Comment: @andreymal, ну вот я потому и написал, потому что спрашивать лучше именно про тип контроллера. А лучше - в принципе модель ноута.

Comment: Кстати. автор. А зачем тебе XP? Ноут обслуживает специфичный софт на заводе в цеху или ты хочешь просто "посёрфить в интернете" на старом железе?

Comment: @donRumata, `хоть бы про проц мать спросил` так упрекаешь как будто от этого XP научится поддерживать GPT разметку... ага щаз...) `если контроллер sata` вот именно - ЕСЛИ. даже 7ку не редко ставили на ide винты, что уж говорить про XP. `зачем XP` вангую - у него винда на актуальном ноуте(uefi которых поддерживают MBR лишь в legacy mode и то не все) полетела, установщик только с XP есть, на актуальном ноуте установка не пошла, вот и пришлось воткнуть винт в старый, а там сюрприз - GPT разметка, которую XP игнорирует напрочь(знаю по опыту).

Comment: @puffleeck, `упрекаешь как будто от этого XP научится поддерживать GPT разметку`. "Windows XP 32-bit does not support GPT. Windows XP 64-bit does support GPT. Support for GPT (GUID Partition Table) was first supported by Windows in Windows XP Professional x64 Edition and Windows Server 2003 x64 Editions (Standard, Enterprise, and Datacenter SKUs)." - https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+xp+gpt+support . Технически - всё-таки поддерживает. Упрекаю, потому что какая разница mbr или gpt, если диск как устройство не видится в принципе? На фото ведь загрузочная флэшка, я прав?

Comment: @puffleeck, `даже 7ку не редко ставили на ide винты` при чём тут винт? До винта надо пройти контроллер. Можешь назвать мне последний ноут с ide винтом? Уверен, что на его ide контроллер нет встроенных дров в дистр xp? `вангую - у него винда на актуальном ноуте` на сколько актуальном? Судя по рамке - это бюджетный ноут с TN матрицей 2015-2017-го года купленный за 20-25к чё-то типа eMachines. Не думаю, что там дорогие чипсеты с поддержкой кучи легаси интерфейсов.

Comment: @puffleeck, ну хз, специально создал чистую виртуалку для winxp и отформатировал винт в gpt. Оригинальный дистр всё отлично увидел: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKyvv.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXvEp.png

Comment: @donRumata, `если не видится в принципе`. в принципе невидится это когда даже биос не видит, а тут фото не биоса а установщика винды и ни слова про видимость в биосе. `на сколько актуальном` дык о том и говорю. на фото явно не актуальный а откопаная с антресолей запаска, откопаная в силу поломки основного. `отлично увидел` только что созданный раздел это конечно показательно против предположительно СЛЕТЕВШЕЙ ВИНДЫ, один из довольно популярных видов слета винды - как раз поврежденные загрузчик\разметка. `при чем тут винт` вот именно, причем тут винт если акцент явно на аббревиатуре **IDE**?

Comment: @puffleeck, winxp умеет работать с gpt, но, вероятно, не может на него устанавливаться. Насколько я представляю, диск всё равно должен показываться, но установить на него будет нельзя - или нет? Вот если там вдруг nvme, то вполне возможно, что не видит.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у меня на x86 XP только что купленный террабайтный SATA HDD винт был не виден самой винде, но в partion assistant разумеется спокойно обнаружился, после смены разметки и винда сразу его увидела и начала подтягивать дрова. x64 не щупал, но сильно сомневаюсь что там лучше. `все равно должен показываться` учитывая что GPT составлена в легаси режиме - начало метки GPT для совместимости идентично MBR метке за счет чего она вообще везде должна поддерживаться, но если правильно понимаю, XP намеренно игнорит GPT разделы дабы не повредить их(так же как и разделы с любой неподдерживаемой ФС).